# Is it possible to adjust the initial Window Size of Windows Server 2008 Server Manager MMC?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

When working with the *Server Manager* window of Windows Server 2008, I am missing a feature/way to configure the initial values of:

- The initial window size
- The splitter width
- The expanded nodes in the Server Manager tree (like "Roles" or "Configuration")

In Windows 2003 and in "normal" MMC applets, I could launch MMC with a special command line parameter to run in adjustment mode and later save all settings.

Unfortunately, all parameters I tried on "*%SystemRoot%\system32\CompMgmtLauncher.exe*" (which is the shortcut traget of the Server Manager), seems to have no effect.

**My question:**

Is there a way to configure the inital values for the Server Manager?

Thanks
Uwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/configuration/q-how-can-i-configure-microsoft-management-console-mmc-to-start-in-a-maximized-window-.aspx

Regards,
Marcel

Comment: Thank you! I am aware of that, I just whished that I did not have to manually "rebuild" the Server Manager, but tell the existing Server Manager its initial values.